# SetStateKbArticleRequest On CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

```
SetStateKbArticleRequest request = new SetStateKbArticleRequest();
                        request.EntityId = KB_ID;
                        request.KbArticleState = KbArticleState.Unapproved;
                        request.KbArticleStatus = 2;
                        serv.Execute(request);
```

I'm migrating from crm 4 to 2011 and I am not able to find anything that replaces this feature! 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a standard `SetStateRequest`

```cs
SetStateRequest request = new SetStateRequest();
request.State = new OptionSetValue(2); // statecode 2 equals Unapproved
request.Status = new OptionSetValue(2); // statuscode 2 equals Unapproved
request.EntityMoniker =  new EntityReference("kbarticle", KB_ID);
SetStateResponse response = (SetStateResponse)serv.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'am Recive this Error

Comment: that assembly is not used by CRM SDK dll, so it belongs to another part of your code

Comment: I change tha SDK according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638702/how-to-change-state-status-in-crm-2013-using-c-sharp) And iam reciving the same error from Visual Studio

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0` doesn't belongs to CRM SDK. This means your project has a reference somewhere to this dll, but has nothing to do with the setstaterequest

Comment: I have deleted ALL the references and Add just the references that the program need too run , and receved the same error...

Comment: which Visual Studio version you are using? which .NET framework you are targeting? did you at least google about that assembly? It has nothing to do with the setstaterequest, it belongs to the project you created. If you remove all the CRM code I'm pretty sure you will get the same error.

Comment: Iam using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET framework 4.5...
I dont understand anything abou the assembly... :X

Answer (score 0):

The SetStateKbArticleRequest was replaced by [SetStateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309493.aspx